# Optimize call for getting records using filters

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb

I am writing a .Net library for getting data from MongoDB. We are using MongoDB.Driver 2.6.1(https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/drivers/csharp/).
My scenario is - suppose there are documents with 3 fields in my DB - _id, SomeId, Status(Status could be - A, B, C). SomeId is not unique. Multiple docs can have same SomeId(like for SomeId = 100, one document can have Status=A, and other for SomeId = 100 can have Status = B as well).

My requirement is to create a list of bson documents where for SomeIds the status is only A. And this list should not contain the SomeIds where the Status=B|C.

For this I have written the below code -

```
var listToBeReturned = new List<BsonDocument>();

var filter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Status", "A");
IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> aggregate = _collection.Aggregate().Match(filter);

var docs = await aggregate.ToListAsync();

foreach(var doc in docs)
{
   var newfilter = Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("SomeId", doc["SomeId"].ToString());
   newfilter = newfilter & Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Status", "B") | Builders<BsonDocument>.Filter.Eq("Status", "C");
   IAggregateFluent<BsonDocument> newaggregate = _collection.Aggregate().Match(newfilter);
   var newlist = await newaggregate.ToListAsync();
   if(newlist.Count == 0)
   {
     listToBeReturned.Add(newlist);
   }
}
return listToBeReturned;
```

Above is working fine but I want to optimize this above method. Is there a better way of doing this? Can we just do the whole filtering in a single call to DB?
Note: I am not planning to use any strongly typed objects only using BsonDocument objects.

**EDIT:**
I missed to mention that Status could've more values like - A,B,C,D,E,.... And I want to fetch the documents where Status=A and for these fetched documents SomeIds, if there are other documents with Status = B, C in collection then dont add it to my return list.

Comment: Im not sure I understand your question , you want to find ALL someIds for Status code "A" but avoid all other someIds for code "B" and "C". So lets say i have SomeId 100 for status code "A" , disregard all bsonDocs for status code "B" and "C" where someId is 100?

Comment: @John I will take a look at Not and will try and let you know.

Comment: @cl0Ud status B or C can also have someId as 100. So I don't want to pick those someIds where status could either be of A,B or C.. I want all those unique someIds where status is only A..

Comment: @cl0ud I don't want to pick document for someId 100 if it have status B or C. But document with someId 100 have status only as A then I will take it.